# Is there a crimp tool, or something, for when you're soldering leads to leads

Tags: soldering

Are there any tools or parts that help when soldering a free-floating component to another one, for example a resistor to an LED? Something that will make some kind of mechanical connection instead of just relying on the solder. I imagine someone has to make some kind of little sleeve or collar that you slide both leads into and then crush, but I've never come across anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are butt splice crimps such as this [Molex one](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/191640014_sd.pdf) which go down to 22 AWG.
Or this [Amp one](http://uk.farnell.com/tyco-electronics-amp/0-0323994-0/crimp-terminal-butt-pidg-yellow/dp/4217627).

But the best way is a [solder sleeve](http://uk.farnell.com/tyco-electronics-raychem/b-155-03/terminal-soldersleeve-3mm-pk100/dp/1292903) like this which is heatshrunk onto the pair of wires. The solder melts at the same time as the sleeving shrinks.
[image: Raychem solder sleeve]

Comment: I marked this one as correct, but I'll probably never buy these. I like the cheap tubing solution and the free Wester Union.

Comment: $0.60 Each!?!  That's ridiculous.  Even soldering the wires by hand and then using normal heat shrink would be cheaper!

Comment: They are used on hi-rel applications where the cost is more bearable, and consistency is valued. Also it's only one operation rather than tin each bare end first, then solder together, then shrink. But I won't defend Farnell or Tyco's pricing here as I have no allegiance to either.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do a "Western Union" ( http://www.tpub.com/neets/book4/32NE0334.GIF ) splice if the wires are flexible enough, I have done them with LEDs to resistors before (I've also made a mess of it before), although I always soldered them as well. I recommend clamping the base of the lead with some pliers before twisting the end lest you break it off the component.

You could combine a union splice with the aluminum tubing idea **unixbigot** mentioned.

There are butt crimps, but I've never seen one small enough that I would want to use it directly with component leads.

Answer (score 2):

At www.modk.it they do this with ordinary 1/16" or 3/32" aluminium tube from hobby stores, which is crimped with crimping pliers. There was a writeup in the latest issue of Make magazine: http://makezine.com/25/modkit/ or http://www.make-digital.com/make/vol25?pg=56#pg56 (not sure if you need to be a subscriber to see that last link).

Here's modkit's doco:

http://www.modk.it/hardware/knobcard

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haN3LBplVu4

Having said that, I always just solder the two leads with about 4mm overlap

```
----------
      -----------
```

And then cover with a 10mm length of heat-shrink tubing.  LEDs with integral resistor
soldered onto one like like this have withstood all the abuse I've given them.

Answer (score 2):

I always just bend each lead into a hook shape, hook the leads together, and then close the hooks into loops. It makes a pretty good physical connection.

Comment: I'm sure it makes a good physical connection, but how's the electrical connection?  I'll bet if you plug it into a scope and move it around, you'd see a lot of noise.

Comment: I make the physical connection by forming the hooks, and then I solder to make the electrical connection.